# Computing surface area and volume of a cylinder - C

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that doesn't return any data. The program computes area and volume of a cylinder. The formulas that i'm trying to use are surfacearea = 2π ∗ (radius)^2 + height ∗ (2π ∗ radius) and volume = π ∗ (radius)^2 ∗ height
I'm having trouble setting up the equations. I have this:

```
surface_area_calc = (2 * PI) ∗ (pow (radius,2)) + height ∗ ((2 * PI) ∗ 
radius);
volume_calc = PI ∗ (pow (radius,2)) ∗ height;
```

but i'm sure it's wrong because i'm getting errors when i try to compile the program. the error i'm getting is saying that 'non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers'.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @xing He hasn't said what compiler he's using, it might not support that switch

Comment: Describing *which* compilation errors you get would go a long way to getting help, but in this case I think I can guess.  You probably get a warning about undeclared function `pow()`, and maybe a link error about that function not being found.  `pow()` is way overkill for squaring a number, so for your particular case, I recommend instead squaring the radius simply by multiplying it by itself.  You will then not need any special header or extra library to support that aspect of your program.

Comment: `PI` shall be a const not a variable. `#define PI 3.14159265358979323846`

Comment: `PI` is already provided in `math.h` as `M_PI`

Comment: i included the <math.h> and defined PI (#define PI = 3.14159265358979323846) but when i compile with -lm i get the error message saying that non-ASCII characters are not allowed outside of literals and identifiers

Comment: To define a `#define` you do *not* use an "assignment" operator like `=`. Just do `#define PI 3.14159265358979323846`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to change a question massively as you did, as this renders comments and answer given so far ununderstandable. Please revert back your edits.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the `=` in the macro

```
#define PI 3.14159...
```

With the `=` it gets copied to the code

```
volume_calc = PI ∗ (pow (radius,2)) ∗ height;
```

becomes

```
volume_calc = = 3.14159 ∗ (pow (radius,2)) ∗ height;
//            ^^^^^^^^^
```

which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices instead of the *wrong*

```
#define PI = 3.14159265358979323846
```

Either stick to using a [pre-processor macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros) and do

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

or use a `const` qualified C variable by doing

```
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

---

As the code uses the library function `pow()` the code ought to provide a prototype for this function to the compiler.

This can simply be achieved by including the appropriate library header. In this case do:

```
#include <math.h>
```

---

To when compilation is done tell the linker to actually link the library implementing the stuff from `math.h` (which often resides in `libm.*`) use (for GCC) the option

```
-lm
```

<sup>[(more here)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)</sup>

Note that when steering the linker via the compiler the libraries *need to be specified after* the source files making use of what the libraries provide.

```
gcc main.c -o main -lm
```

The following most likely will fail

```
gcc -lm main.c -o main
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you in Linux? Is so, do:

```
#include <math.h>
```

at the top of your code and compile with `-lm`, like this:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lm
```